# How can I get Leksah's candy to render properly in OS X?

Tags: haskell, fonts, leksah

The [Leksah](http://leksah.org) IDE for Haskell has an interesting "candy" feature which renders certain operators like == as special symbols (a triple equals sign in this case). On OS X (Mountain Lion, 10.8.2, if it matters), these special symbols just show up as boxes. Googling reveals that others have had this issue but I couldn't find any solutions.

Does anybody know how to make the candy fonts work correctly in Leksah on OS X?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but have you tried changing the font? You can try using something like Deaj Vu Sans Mono which is both a great looking font *and* replete with all the weird characters you can imagine.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: I would advise against this “candy” feature because it breaks alignment (e.g. branches of `case`, multi-way if).